# Understanding sed

Tags: linux, bash, sed, manpage, info

I am trying to understand how

```
sed 's/\^\[/\o33/g;s/\[1G\[/\[27G\[/' /var/log/boot
```

worked and what the pieces mean. The man page I read just confused me more and I tried the info sai Id but had no idea how to work it! I'm pretty new to Linux. Debian is my first distro but seemed like a rather logical place to start as it is a root of many others and has been around a while so probably is doing stuff well and fairly standardized. I am running Wheezy 64 bit as fyi if needed.

Comment: Which part don't you understand? The `s///` command, the regular expressions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `sed` command is a *stream editor*, reading its file (or STDIN) for input, applying commands to the input, and presenting the results (if any) to the output (STDOUT).

The general syntax for `sed` is

```
sed [OPTIONS] COMMAND FILE
```

In the shell command you gave:

`sed 's/\^\[/\o33/g;s/\[1G\[/\[27G\[/' /var/log/boot`

the `sed` command is `s/\^\[/\o33/g;s/\[1G\[/\[27G\[/'` and `/var/log/boot` is the file.

The given `sed` command is actually two separate commands:

1. `s/\^\[/\o33/g`
2. `s/\[1G\[/\[27G\[/`

The intent of #1, the `s` (substitute) command, is to replace all occurrences of `'^['` with an octal value of `033` (the `ESC` character).  However, there is a mistake in this `sed` command.  The proper bash syntax for an escaped octal code is `\nnn`, so the proper way for this `sed` command to have been written is:

`s/\^\[/\033/g`

Notice the trailing `g` after the replacement string? It means to perform a *global* replacement; without it, only the first occurrence would be changed.

The purpose of #2 is to replace all occurrences of the string `\[1G\[` with `\[27G\[`.  However, this command also has a mistake: a trailing `g` is needed to cause a global replacement.  So, this second command needs to be written like this:

`s/\[1G\[/\[27G\[/g`

Finally, putting all this together, the two `sed` commands are applied across the contents of the `/var/log/boot` file, where the output has had all occurrences of `^[` converted into `\033`, and the strings `\[1G\[` have been converted to `\[27G\[`.

Comment: Thanks for the in depth answer. To be honest It will take me some looking to understand it all. So far I think replacing the lead '^[' to the 'esc' character are what allows for the fairly easy to speed read color coding. I had read that the fact it does this is a bug that has been standing and reported. (This suggests it probably has been around a little while.)

Comment: just wanted to say thanks for the answer and hope now you will get a notification that I sent this.

Comment: I haven't played with this much until recently. However, I would like to point out that when I substituted 'o33' with '033' (which is correct by octal) the 'nice' color coding disappeared. I played with the other substitution of '/' vs '/g' with and without '033' and was able to prove to myself that for some reason it was the octal and NOT the global repeat that was involved.